# Docker container Django debug mode true, still production mode

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I have dockerized django app. And I have an .env file with debug=1. But when I run the docker container it is in apparently in production mode: debug=false.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - ./zijn:/app
    command: >
      sh -c " python manage.py wait_for_db &&
              python ./manage.py migrate &&      
              python ./manage.py runserver 0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=zijn
      - DB_USER=zijn
      - DB_PASS=235711
      - DEBUG=1
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine

    volumes:
      - dev-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=dzijn
      - POSTGRES_USER=zijn
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=235711

volumes:
  dev-db-data:
  dev-static-data:
```

and the .env file:

```
DEBUG=1
SECRET_KEY="django-insecure-kwuz7%@967xvpdnf7go%r#d%lgl^c9ah%!_08l@%x=s4e4&+(u"
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
DB_NAME="zijn"
DB_USER="zijn"
DB_PASS="235711"
DB_HOST=db
DB-PORT=54326
```

And also my settings.py is debug mode=True:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG') == "True"



ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV = os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS')
if ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV.split(','))
```

Because it returns the message:

```
 dotenv.read_dotenv()
dwl_backend-app-1  | CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.
```

And also the templates are not loaded.

Question: how to start docker container with debug=True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you set `DEBUG=1` but then you checking `os.environ.get('DEBUG') == "True"` which is always `False`.

Try to change it to `os.environ.get('DEBUG') == "1"`

Comment: @Andej. oh. Can you explain why that works what you suggested. I don't understan this.Anyway thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: @mightycodeNewton You've set `DEBUG=1`, so `os.environ.get('DEBUG')` returns string `"1"` (without quotes). You're then comparing this string to `"True"`, and `"1" == "True"` is always `False`.